# Vitest mocks function available in template but not in script

Tags: vue-test-utils, vitest

I have mocked function in my global config

```
config.global.mocks.route = (name) => route(name, undefined, undefined, Ziggy);
```

If I access `route()` inside the `<template>` everything works as expected but if I try to access `rotue()` inside method

```
const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('login'), {
        onFinish: () => form.reset('password'),
    });
};
```

I get an error that `ReferenceError: route is not defined`

Any ideas why?

Comment: hey @DkiCRO did you ever solve this? I'm struggling with this now too.